# temporary change current time as static value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I need in current session,   set to postgres some value manually for example `2016-01-25 12:13:14` as current time.

That is, I need temporary, at call `LOCALTIMESTAMP(0)` returned this static value: `2016-01-25 12:13:14` and not really and right date time.

It's possible? and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're doing this because of a script. Can't you just replace all occurences of `LOCALTIMESTAM(0)` to your value with something like notepad++?

Edit:

according to this [postgresql.org post](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1393426627566-5793703.post@n5.nabble.com) you can in fact override a function.
But I wouldn't know if it works for sure.

Comment: I need this just for testing, but querys and procedures are in many several files, really many for changing in notepad++, So If possible what I asking, would be just nice